# GraphQL Subscription doesn't listen all new creations - react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, prisma

[image]

I am using GraphQL Subscription with Prisma (http://prismagraphql.com/) and react + react-apollo.

In the example above, the number '3' has not been listened by `subscribeToMore(`. Hence query `chatsQueryConnection` has not been updated.

The number '3' has been successfully created because this number appears after the page has been refreshed.

`subscribeToMore` Listner:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.chatsQueryConnection.subscribeToMore({
      document: CHAT_SUBSCRIPTION,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        console.log('componentDidMountSub')
        if (!subscriptionData) {
          return prev
        }
        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          chatsConnection: {
            __typename: 'ChatConnection',
            edges: [
              ...prev.chatsConnection.edges,
              subscriptionData.data.chat
            ]
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

GrqphQL subscription Query:

```
const CHAT_SUBSCRIPTION = gql `
  subscription {
    chat(where:{mutation_in: CREATED}) {
      node {
        id
        message
        author {
          name
          nameFile
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/alan345/naperg/blob/master/react/src/components/chat/ChatsPageList.js)

[Apollo subscription Documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more)

[Prisma subscription Documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/prisma-api/subscriptions-aey0vohche/#subscribing-to-created-nodes)

Comment: Did you learn more about this? Can you provide a minimal reproduction?

Comment: Hi @marktani, following the deep dive, I think this issue is related to: https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/how-to-unsubscribe-when-user-leave-the-page-react/3530. It seems that the server saturated because frontend never unsubscribe